# Sorting a range in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have several similar examples that all purport to work, but mine does not. Excel 2013, Office 365.

```
' Sort the "URLs" worksheet after update
Worksheets("URLs").Activate
lngLastRow = Cells(65536, Range.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set Range = Worksheets("URLs").Range("A3:E" & lngLastRow)

Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B4:B" & lngLastRow), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A4:A" & lngLastRow), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Worksheets("URLs").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:E" & lngLastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Even when I don't use headers (change Range("A3") to "A4") and manually use an end range ("33" instead of lngLastRow), I get the error "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument".

I created this macro using the recorder. I don't know why a recorded macro would not work in a macro.

I have never gotten anything with a ":=" to work. I've always had to work around that, but in this case, I can't figure that out either.

Comment: try to change `Key:=Range("B4:B" & lngLastRow)` to `Key:=Worksheets("URLs").Range("B4:B" & lngLastRow)`. For `Range("A3:E" & lngLastRow)` and `Range("A4:E" & lngLastRow)` the same thing. Let us know if it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
' Sort the "URLs" worksheet after update
Sub Macro1()
    Worksheets("URLs").Activate
    Dim Range As Range
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    lngLastRow = Worksheets("URLs").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Range = Worksheets("URLs").Range("A3:E" & lngLastRow)

    Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("URLs").Range("B4:B" & lngLastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Worksheets("URLs").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("URLs").Range("A4:A" & lngLastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("URLs").Sort
        .SetRange Worksheets("URLs").Range("A3:E" & lngLastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked. Can you explain why? I know it wasn't the change to lngLastRow. Thanks

Comment: @DrStrangepork - basic debugging will help explain why. Basically you were referencing ranges/cells incorrectly. And obviously you didn't show us how you declared your variables - so I can't tell you if you did something wrong with that - but I declared lngLastRow and Range in a standard fashion. You didn't seem to use the Range variable at all though - so that probably wasn't necessary.

Comment: Reason I ask is I copied my example right out of a microsoft.com support forum, and the OP said that code fixed their issue. I only edited the cell #'s. Once you do 'Worksheets("URLs").Activate', all your 'Worksheets("URLs").' calls should be redundant. But it's fine, it works. I find VBA to be rather unintuitive.